# Two different sets of radio buttons with independent behavior

Tags: css, html, radio-button

I have two different sections that comprise of two radio buttons with different values and IDs. The problem is that I can check only **one** button at a time, but I need these two sets of radio buttons work independently, i.e. in each set of radio buttons one button could be checked.
Here's the HTML:

```
<section class="radio_holder_1">
    <div class="radio">
        <input id="share_this" type="radio" name="option_type" value="share_this" checked>
        <label class="hmc_radiolabel" for="share_this">Share Picture</label>
        <input id="use_4_now" type="radio" name="option_type" value="use_4_now">
        <label class="hmc_radiolabel" for="use_4_now">Instant Use</label>
    </div>
</section>
    <hr>
<section class="radio_holder_2">
    <div class="radio_2">
       <input id="free" type="radio" name="option_type" value="free" checked>
       <label class="hmc_radiolabel" for="free">FREE</label>
       <input id="premium" type="radio" name="option_type" value="premium">
       <label class="hmc_radiolabel" for="premium">VIP</label>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Simply give the radio buttons from the other set a different value for the `name` attribute.

Comment: Thanks @Xufox! That was a stupid omission from my side...

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your name. Use a different name for the second selection and it should work.

```
<section class="radio_holder_1">
<div class="radio">
<input id="share_this" type="radio" name="option_type" value="share_this" checked>
<label class="hmc_radiolabel" for="share_this">Share Picture</label>
<input id="use_4_now" type="radio" name="option_type" value="use_4_now">
<label class="hmc_radiolabel" for="use_4_now">Instant Use</label>
</div>
</section>
<hr>
<section class="radio_holder_2">
<div class="radio_2">
<input id="free" type="radio" name="option_type2" value="free" checked>
<label class="hmc_radiolabel" for="free">FREE</label>
<input id="premium" type="radio" name="option_type2" value="premium">
<label class="hmc_radiolabel" for="premium">VIP</label>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks @Xufox. I forgot to revert the rest of the code!